# Dropzone.js failed to load resource in safari or mac

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5.1, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone in laravel 5.1 but it's working in firefox, chrome in windows. once run in mac it's response error with  `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

is there any problem with php code ?

I have written following code of javascript:

```
var dropZone = new Dropzone($(".dropzone").get(0),{
          url: BASE_URL+'user/board/uploadimages',
          uploadMultiple: true,
          parallelUploads: 100,
          maxFiles: 100,
          maxFilesize: 5,
          dictFileTooBig: 'Image is bigger than 5MB',
          addRemoveLinks: false,
          autoProcessQueue: true,
          dictDefaultMessage: "<label class='dropzone-message-container'><i class='fa fa-cloud-upload'></i><div class='clearfix'></div> Drop images to upload</label>",
          acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.JPEG,.JPG,.PNG,.GIF",
          init: function()
          {
              thisDropzone = this;

            this.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){
              hiddenBoardID = $("#dropZone .hiddenBoardID").val();
              formData.append('hiddenBoardID', hiddenBoardID);
            });
            this.on('thumbnail', function(file) {
              console.log(file.width);
                if ( file.width < 1000) {
                  file.rejectDimensions();
                }
                else {
                  file.acceptDimensions();
                }
            });
            this.on("success",function(file, response){


              if(response.success){
                 toastr.success(response.message,"Success");
                 setTimeout(function(){
                     dropZone.removeFile(file);
                     $("#dropZone").modal("hide");
                 },2000);
                $("#imageListing .image-container").empty().html(response.html);
              }else{
                toastr.warning(response.message,"Error");
              }
            });
            this.on("complete", function(file) {
            });
            this.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
            });

          },
          accept: function(file, done) {
            file.acceptDimensions = done;
            file.rejectDimensions = function() {
              done('The image must be at least 1000 pixels in width');
            };
          },
        });
```

please check following image when I try to upload image in mac.

[image]

I have check code in dropzone.js official page as well but hot find out this issue.

Please help for this issue.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?